# how to show only primary connection in d3plus rings

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

I working around the d3plus rings and in which I need to show only the primary connection in the ring.

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://www.d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>
<div id="viz"></div>
<script>
  var connections = [ {"source": "alpha", "target": "beta"},
                      {"source": "alpha", "target": "gamma"},
                      {"source": "beta", "target": "delta"},
                      {"source": "beta", "target": "epsilon"},
                      {"source": "zeta", "target": "gamma"},
                      {"source": "theta", "target": "gamma"},
                      {"source": "eta", "target": "gamma"} ]
var visualization = d3plus.viz()
.container("#viz")  // container DIV to hold the visualization
.type("rings")      // visualization type
.edges(connections) // list of node connections
.focus("alpha")     // ID of the initial center node
.draw()             // finally, draw the visualization!
```

When `Gamma` is selected then `Alpha`,`Zeta`,`Theta` & `Eta` should be displayed. I tried the method `.color` which says `.color(String|Function|Object)` use `key secondary` accepting values `color`. How to write the expression for this?
Please visit  [D3 Plus Documentation](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations)

[image]

Clicked on `Beta` should show 
[image]

Comment: what is the required behaviour ? Can you upload an image ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117387/discussion-between-gupteshwari-and-dragon-slayer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commenting the code which creates the list of secondary nodes to the centered node helped me to achieve what I was trying to. see the commented line

```
a = (angle-(s*children/2)+(s/2))+((s)*i)
  d.d3plus.radians = a
  d.d3plus.x = vars.width.viz/2 + ((secondaryRing) * Math.cos(a))
  d.d3plus.y = vars.height.viz/2 + ((secondaryRing) * Math.sin(a))
  //secondaries.push(d)    THE LINE I COMMENTED AND GOT IT WORKING
```

Comment: You probably have to download d3plus.js, tweak it and provide it yourself, right? Or is there a way to load the script from the web and tweak the behaviour afterwards?